# Apple wired keyboard doesn't work being plugged in usb 3.0 port

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard

My Apple wired keyboard doesn't work if it is plugged into an USB 3.0 port on my Samsung laptop.

As far as I understand the problem is in USB 2.0 hub built-in Apple keyboard, and it's not work well with USB 3.0 hub within laptop.

Please note that it works properly being plugged in USB 2.0 port in the same laptop.

Is there way to switch USB3 ports to USB2 mode? Or another way to get keyboard working?

The inconvenience is that USB2 ports in my laptop are located at the right side, but it's convenient to me to plug keyboard at the left.

Comment: Does this usb3 port work with real usb3 devices? And what is your operating system ?

Comment: OS Win 7 x64. I have no usb 3 devices to test ports. Usual devices like USB flash drive works correctly.

Comment: Have you a proper driver for usb3 such as Renesas Electronics USB 3.0 Driver?

Comment: No. :-). Looking for and trying to install.

Comment: Did you try entering the BIOS/Setup of the PC? Usually there is an option where you can change the USB 3.0 to USB 2.0

Comment: Note the Apple Keyboard does work with USB3 ports. e.g. on my Apple Mini, so I suggest the issue is with the laptop and its software

Comment: How old is the Apple Keyboard? The older USB 2.0 keyboards actually had USB 1.1 hubs and maybe that's the problem.  In any case, USB 3.0 ports automatically switch to 2.0 when plugged in because the plugs are different.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments.
Rene Brakus: Yes, I've entered BIOS. There's no options related to USB to change.
Mark: I think so. Yet Samsung's drivers for USB 3.0 (from samsung.com) doesn't install properly...
Old Pro: I've bought it last winter (the end of '12 or beginning of '13) but I don't know how many years my keyboard stayed at dealer's stocks. There's inscription at hte back side: (c) 2007 Apple Inc.

Comment: This must be what's going on for me too... Before finding this thread I found a bunch of others describing similar issues. I remember reading that someone's keyboard worked when plugged into a USB hub but not the laptop. I assume the Hub successfully interfaces with USB 3 in the laptop and then the keyboard can talk to the hub? Maybe if you have a USB hub lying around you could try that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your BIOS just doesn't agree with your keyboard,
possibly too old to be used in such a new port.

The only suggestion I can make is to look for a BIOS update that might improve
the situation, either working with that keyboard or having an option for USB2 emulation.

Otherwise, you might need a newer keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

A BIOS on a IBM compatible (tm) PC used to work with PS2 port. Support for that was included in the BIOS and an old PC with an OLD BIOS will not recognise an USB keyboard.

This was a problem when people got the  'new' USB 1 based keyboards. An old keyboard was needed to enter the BIOS, the new one only worked after booting the OS (and with the OS the USB drivers).

Eventually (present time) we worked around that by adding **limited** USB support to the BIOS. (Limited as in no support for most devices except for mouse and keyboards). This way you can use your keyboard before booting. When the OS finally initialises its drivers it takes over from the old BIOS hooks.

Now we finally get to the problem. The USB3 controller is different from older USB1|2 controllers. Many BIOSses do not support it yet. (It will work fine from the OS once the OS boots and loads all drivers, including USB2 and USB3 drivers).  But as long as you are in the BIOS you need to use the USB2 ports.

TL;DR; It should work:

1. **After** the OS is loaded and takes over.
2. And assuming there are no weird incompatibilities either from the USB3 implementation or because the keyboard integrated hub acts in a non-standard fashion.

Can you test the last by plugging the apple keyboard in another computer with a USB3 port?

Comment: At other PC (desktop) works fine. Seems the problem is in chipset drivers of my laptop.